# Como puedo hacer una jerarquía a una serie de números?

Tags: php

Hola un saludo a todos. 
Mi consulta es que tengo una array en php con las notas de alumnos ordenados de mayor a menor y tengo que establecer un puesto según su nota.

El resultado debe ser algo similar a este ejemplo

```
 9.8 -> 1
 9.7 -> 2
 9.6 -> 3
 9.4 -> 4
 9.4 -> 4
 9.3 -> 6
 9.2 -> 7
 9.2 -> 7
 9.2 -> 7
 9.1 -> 10
 9.1 -> 10
 9.1 -> 10
 8.9 -> 13
```

De antemano agradezco su ayuda.

Comment: ¿Como determinas el puesto?

Comment: Hola y bienvenido a [es.so]. Revisa el apartado [ask] para crear una publicación que sea de mayor interés y así encontrar una respuesta a tu pregunta. También puedes hacer el [tour] y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. Recuerda añadir el código que tienes hasta el momento en el formato de código que se facilita en [edit]

Comment: ¿Qué te parece registrar todas las notas en un array enumerado y hacer uso de `sort()`? Después le sumas uno al índice y obtendrás lo que buscas... ¿Qué has probado?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

¿Qué te parece registrar todas las notas en un array enumerado y hacer uso de `rsort()`? Después le sumas uno al índice y obtendrás lo que buscas:

```
<?php

$ns=[
 9.8, 9.7, 9.6, 9.4, 9.4, 9.3, 
 9.2, 9.2, 9.2, 9.1, 9.1, 9.1, 
 8.9,
];

rsort($ns);

$m=0;
$j=0;
foreach($ns as $i=>$n){
    if($m!=$n){
        $m=$n;
        $j=$i;
    }
    echo $n.' -> '.($j+1).'<br/>';
}
```

Obteniendo:

```
9.8 -> 1
9.7 -> 2
9.6 -> 3
9.4 -> 4
9.4 -> 4
9.3 -> 6
9.2 -> 7
9.2 -> 7
9.2 -> 7
9.1 -> 10
9.1 -> 10
9.1 -> 10
8.9 -> 13
```

Espero que sea lo que buscabas

Comment: gracias, pero la situación es la siguiente: se asigna la misma jerarquía a los números duplicados. Sin embargo, la presencia de números duplicados afecta a la jerarquía de los números siguientes. Por ejemplo, en una lista de números enteros ordenados en orden ascendente, si el número 10 aparece dos veces y tiene una jerarquía de 5, entonces el número 11 tendría una jerarquía de 7 (ningún número tendría jerarquía de 6) si me puedes ayudar te lo agradecería mucho

Comment: Ok, respuesta actualizada, espero que te sirva

Comment: Eso es lo que necesitaba gracias por el apoyo

Comment: Genial, [Recuerda validar y votar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) y [Gana +2 de reputación](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3762/119615)

Answer (score 0):

lo primero sería saber que puestos tienes, como notas iguales comparten el mismo puesto, hay que saber cuantas notas diferentes existen. Seguidamente se asignan las notas a los puestos.

```
<?php

$arr_notas = [
    9.9,

    9.8, 
    9.8,

    9.2,

    8.5, 
    8.5, 
    8.5, 

    7.2,
];

// Averiguamos los puestos existentes
// Partimos del puesto 1 para la nota mas alta, y su número se incrementa en 1
// segun decrecen las notas
// Dos o más notas iguales comparten el mismo puesto
$arr_notas_unicas = array_values(array_unique($arr_notas));
print_r($arr_notas_unicas); // HACK: imprime las diferentes notas
$arr_puestos = range(1, count($arr_notas_unicas));
print_r($arr_puestos); // HACK: imprime los puestos

// Iremos asignando las notas, usando los arrays de notas únicas y puestos
foreach ($arr_puestos as $key => $puesto) {

    $nota_puesto = $arr_notas_unicas[$key];

    // Si quieres imprimir los resultados:
    printResults($arr_notas, $nota_puesto, $puesto);

}

function printResults($arr_notas, $nota_puesto, $puesto)
{
    $final_tag = PHP_EOL; // o '<br>' según donde quieras la salida
    foreach ($arr_notas as $nota) {
        if ($nota === $nota_puesto) {
            echo $nota . ' -> ' . $puesto . $final_tag;
        }
    }
}
```

El script tendrá esta salida (tendrás que quitar las trazas):

```
Array
(
    [0] => 9.9
    [1] => 9.8
    [2] => 9.2
    [3] => 8.5
    [4] => 7.2
)
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 3
    [3] => 4
    [4] => 5
)
9.9 -> 1
9.8 -> 2
9.8 -> 2
9.2 -> 3
8.5 -> 4
8.5 -> 4
8.5 -> 4
7.2 -> 5
```

***Nota:*** esto funciona si los puestos son consecutivos: 1,2,3,4,5,...
si saltan sin criterio aparente, 1,2,3,5,8,... mientras tengas el número correcto de puestos la solución es la misma, solo que no hay que crear los puestos (entiendo que ya los tienes).

Por ejemplo si `$arr_puestos` tuviera 1,2,3,7,10: la salida sería:

```
9.9 -> 1
9.8 -> 2
9.8 -> 2
9.2 -> 3
8.5 -> 7
8.5 -> 7
8.5 -> 7
7.2 -> 10
```

> Editado. Atendiendo al comentario que aclara el problema.

```
<?php

$arr_notas = [
    9.9,

    9.8, 
    9.8,

    9.2,

    8.5, 
    8.5, 
    8.5, 

    7.2,
];

// Dos o más notas iguales comparten el mismo puesto: un puesto por 
// cada grupo de notas iguales
//
// Partimos del puesto 1 para la nota mas alta. Su número se incrementa
// según decrecen las notas, siendo el número da cada nuevo puesto, el 
// valor del puesto anterior + el número de notas repetidas en ese puesto 
$arr_notas_unicas = array_unique($arr_notas);
$arr_keys_notas_unicas = array_keys($arr_notas_unicas);
// con count($arr_notas_unicas) tendríamos el número de puestos

// Iremos asignando las notas y puestos
$contador = 0;
$puesto   = 1;
$nota_anterior = $arr_notas[0];
foreach ($arr_notas as $nota) {
    if ($nota_anterior !== $nota) {
        $contador++;
        $puesto = $arr_keys_notas_unicas[$contador] + 1;
    }
    echo $nota . ' -> ' . $puesto . PHP_EOL;

    $nota_anterior = $nota;
}
```

Salida:

```
9.9 -> 1
9.8 -> 2
9.8 -> 2
9.2 -> 4
8.5 -> 5
8.5 -> 5
8.5 -> 5
7.2 -> 8
```

**Explicación:** cuando filtramos las notas con `array_unique($arr_notas)`, eliminando las repeticiones tenemos el número de puestos existente (igual al número de elementos), si bien estos no son consecutivos (si se repiten notas), nos los da el funcionamiento de la propia función [array_unique()](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/324165/comportamiento-de-array-unique-en-php), sus claves no serán tampoco consecutivas (si se repiten notas), es un reflejo de los puestos, si bien comienza en 0 por lo que a cada `$key` se le añade 1 para obtener el puesto a imprimir. ¿Cómo sabemos cuando varia el puesto y por tanto obtenemos el siguiente indice? cuando la nota que vamos a imprimir es diferente a la anterior...

Comment: Hola gracias por el apoyo solo queria consultarte algo adicional y es que asigna la misma jerarquía a los números duplicados. Sin embargo, la presencia de números duplicados afecta a la jerarquía de los números siguientes. Por ejemplo, en una lista de números enteros ordenados en orden ascendente, si el número 10 aparece dos veces y tiene una jerarquía de 5, entonces el número 11 tendría una jerarquía de 7 (ningún número tendría jerarquía de 6), si me puedes ayudar. te agradesco de antemano

Comment: Muchas gracias por el apoyo así es el resultado que necesito