# Comportamiento de array_unique en PHP

Tags: php

He observado que al usar `array_unique()`, los indices no son correlativos en el array obtenido, es decir, por ejemplop `0,1,2,3,4`.

Ejemplo con *PHP 7.1.0, 7.3.5, 7.4.0*:

```
$arr_numbers = [
    1,
    1,
    2,
    3,
    5,
    5,
    5,
    8,
    8,
    9,
    11
];

// Imprime los diferentes números
$arr_unique_numbers = array_unique($arr_numbers);
print_r($arr_unique_numbers);
```

Resultado:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [2] => 2
    [3] => 3
    [4] => 5
    [7] => 8
    [9] => 9
    [10] => 11
)
```

Esto obliga a ***reindexar, cuando vamos a usar los indices del array resultante***:

```
// Imprime los diferentes números con los indices correctos
$arr_unique_numbers = array_values(array_unique($arr_numbers));
print_r($arr_unique_numbers);
```

Salida:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 3
    [3] => 5
    [4] => 8
    [5] => 9
    [6] => 11
)
```

Este comportamiento es un problema si no lo tenemos en mente porque puede ocasionar fallos... **¿Por qué estos indices?**

No he visto nada al respecto en la
[documentación de array_unique()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.array-unique.php).

Comment: La documentación que estás linkeando dice: *"Nótese que se conservan las claves. array_unique() ordena los valores tratándolos como cadenas, manteniendo la primera clave encontrada por cada valor e ignorando las demás claves. Esto no significa que será mantenida la clave relacionada con el primer valor encontrado del array no ordenado."* Ahí te está diciendo que las claves del **array** no van a ser modificadas y que al eliminarse los ocurrencias de un mismo valor se va a conservar la pareja **clave => valor** de tan solo una de ellas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`array_unique()` elimina los elementos repetidos del array, quedando huecos en los índices las posiciones de los elementos eliminados. Se precisa reindexar en caso necesario.

Answer (score 1):

`array_unique` elimina repeticiones, esto altera el array resultante dejando saltos entre índices.

De [php.net](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php)

> Note that keys are preserved. If multiple elements compare equal under
>   the given sort_flags, then the key and value of the first equal
>   element will be retained.